# How to add package name in Kotlin Jupyter

Tags: kotlin, jupyter-notebook

I am unable to add the package name in the kotlin Jupyter notebook. I have tried example from kotlin documentation https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html

1. Am new to kotlin
2. First time using kotlin Jupyter notebook

**Code**

```
package org.example

fun printMessage() { /*...*/ }
class Message { /*...*/ }
```

**Exception Details**

```
Front-end Internal error: Failed to analyze declaration Line_66_jupyter
File being compiled: (1,20) in Line_66.jupyter.kts
The root cause org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.NoDescriptorForDeclarationException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.BasicAbsentDescriptorHandler.diagnoseDescriptorNotFound(AbsentDescriptorHandler.kt:18)
```

From the above exception, my understanding is that Kotlin Jupyter notebook

1. Doesn't understand package as keyword
2. Or it doesn't support package declaration

Code

Comment: Have you tried to remove the package declaration and run it again?

Comment: yes and that will work. The point is if you are doing a project you need a package to define our class in your package. Kotlin Jupyter notebook does not all that